# I'm trying to create a frequency analysis for a caeser cipher,However I can't seem to get an output

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a code that I want to count the frequency of letters being used in a cipher text then compare it to `ETAOINSHRDLCUMWFGYPBVKJXQZ`. I then want it to suggest a key to use when decrypting however I can't get an output from my current coding.

```
englishLetterFreq = {'E', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'I', 'N', 'S', 'H', 'R', 'D', 'L', 'C', 'U', 'M', 'W', 'F', 'G', 'Y', 'P', 'B', 'V', 'K', 'J', 'X', 'Q', 'Z'}
ETAOIN = 'ETAOINSHRDLCUMWFGYPBVKJXQZ'
LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'


def getLetterCount(message):
    letterCount = {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 0, 'F': 0, 'G': 0, 'H': 0, 'I': 0, 'J': 0, 'K': 0, 'L': 0, 'M': 0, 'N': 0, 'O': 0, 'P': 0, 'Q': 0, 'R': 0, 'S': 0, 'T': 0, 'U': 0, 'V': 0, 'W': 0, 'X': 0, 'Y': 0, 'Z': 0}

    for letter in message.upper():
        if letter in LETTERS:
            letterCount[letter] +=1
            print('LETTERS {}'.format(letterCount))
    return letterCount

def getItemAtIndexZero(x):
    return x[0]


def getFrequencyOrder(message):
    letterToFreq = getLetterCount(message)
    letterToFreq = {}
    for letter in LETTERS:
        if letterToFreq[letter] not in freqToletter:
            freqToLetter[letterToFreq[letter]] = [letter]
        else:
            freqToLetter[letterToFreq[letter]].append(letter)

    for freq in freqToLetter:
        freqToLetter[freq].sort(key=ETAOIN.find, reverse=True)
        freqToLetter[freq] = ".join(freqToLetter[freq])"
        freqPairs = list(freqToLetter.items())
        freqPairs.sort(key=getItemAtIndexZero, reverse=True)
        freqOrder = []
        for freqPair in freqPairs:
            freqOrder.append(freqPair[1])
        return".join(freqOrder)"


def englishFreqMatchScore(message):

    freqOrder = getFrequencyOrder(message)
    matchScore = 0
    for commonLetter in ETAOIN[:6]:
        if commonLetter in freqOrder[:6]:
            matchScore += 1
    for uncommonLetter in ETAOIN[-6:]:
        if uncommonLetter in freqOrder[-6:]:
            matchScore += 1
            print("{}",englsishFreqMatchScore)
    return matchScore
```

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and [edit] your post.

Comment: On a general note. This is slightly advanced but, have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter this will save you a lot of time now and in the future with this type of tasks

Comment: why would you call getLetterCount if you are just going to overwrite it on the following line

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following. I am sorry for not correcting your code in place but sometimes rewritting something is easier than correcting it. Feel free to ask me if something is not clear.

```
from collections import Counter


def decr(text, jump):
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    decryption = ''
    for char in text.lower():
        ind = alpha.find(char)
        if ind != -1:
            decryption += alpha[ind - jump]
        else:
            decryption += char
    return decryption

to_dec = r'Max yheehpbgz mhhe teehpl rhn mh xgvkrim t mxqm pbma t lbfiex hyylxm tezhkbmaf - telh dghpg tl Vtxltk vbiaxk. By rhn tkx nlbgz 13 tl max dxr, max kxlnem bl lbfbetk mh tg khm13 xgvkrimbhg. By rhn nlx "znxll" tl max dxr, max tezhkbmaf mkbxl mh ybgw max kbzam dxr tgw wxvkriml max lmkbgz ur znxllbgz. B telh pkhmx t lftee tkmbvex (pbma lhnkvx inuebvtmbhg) tuhnm ybgwbgz max kbzam dxr bg tg ngdghpg vhgmxqm hy tg xgvkrimxw mxqm. By rhn ptgm mh dghp fhkx, B abzaer kxvhffxgm mabl uhhd.'

alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
freq = 'etaoinsrhdlucmfywgpbvkxqjz'
n = 3

c = Counter(''.join(x for x in to_dec.lower() if x in alpha))
order = ''.join(x[0] for x in c.most_common())

f = lambda x: alpha.find(x[0]) - alpha.find(x[1])
nums = [f(x) if f(x) >= 0 else f(x) + 26 for x in zip(order, freq)]

d = Counter(nums)

for i in d.most_common(n):
    key = i[0]
    print('Trying Ceasar with n = {}'.format(key))
    print(decr(to_dec, key))
    print()
```

Dissapointingly enough (but not strangely), every time you run this code you **might** get a different result. This is a no-go but it happens due to `collections.Counter().most_common()` which when to items have the same count, returns them with an *arbitrary* order. But then again, as the size of the text that goes in to be encrypted increases, the possibility of having two letters with the exact same count deminishes. Setting the `n` to 1 also helps (code provides one suggestion for the ceasar key).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What is the book that you mentioned in the encrypted text?